# Is aluminum siding compatible with vinyl siding?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

I had a contractor come and remove the wall unit ACs in replacement of mini split systems. They closed off the hole, but didn't put siding on the exterior. The siding is aluminum. I can take pieces from the back of my garage to repair the holes. Is vinyl siding compatible with Aluminum siding to work together. How the garage wall looks is of no concern as it's blocked by trees.
[image: Back wall]

[image: Side wall]

Comment: Sure. It won't look good, but it can be done. Now if you're asking, How can it be done so it looks good, that's a different question.

Comment: I would be concern that the vinyl will not fit right to the aluminum and pop loose with some wind.  The thickness of the two might be too much difference.

Comment: Apparently, according to a web-search, aluminum siding is still available. Probably better to stick to replacement aluminum pieces.

Comment: The front I might consider replacing the whole section/front.  Patching that hole will not look good, even with stuff from the back.  Back and front will have a different fade of colour over time.

Comment: "Is vinyl siding compatible with aluminum siding?" seems to be a reasonably objective question, but the answer may well depend on which brands of siding we're talking about. I'm not sure if different brands of vinyl siding are compatible with each other. Your best bet, if you want to go down this road, may be to try it and see...

Answer (score 1):

Chemically yes it's compatible the two products can be used together with no ill effects.

Physically, well the "boards" will likely have different profiles and will probably not link together easily but there will be a trim that you can use at the join.

Practically,  before ripping up your garage wall visit a building salvage yard or three, you may be able to find compatable used aluminum siding there, this will simplify your task and possibly save you money too.

Answer (score 0):

No, vinyl siding is not compatible with aluminum. Or maybe it is, depending on your personal appearance and installation expectations.

- Vinyl and aluminum have probably never been made by the same company. Since sizes, styles, and flange designs are largely proprietary, even just *vinyl* from two companies may not mate together well.
- Board heights are not likely to match. If you were repairing one board, you could maybe trim it or otherwise get it to work. With three boards stacked you'd have trouble getting siding of differing board heights to fit.
- Flange shapes are much different for metal siding than for vinyl. The former has a flat, tight hem. the latter has a somewhat bulbous, rounded profile. While these *could* work together, it's likely that they won't.
- Finally, appearance. Older aluminum siding tends to have sharply creased corners and either a smooth or embossed texture. This contrasts somewhat with typical vinyl, which tends to have more rounded corners and a fine woodgrain texture stamped into it, if anything.

Aluminum hasn't been commonly manufactured for decades--it was supplanted with vinyl-coated steel for cost and durability reasons. However, you may find someone with some old or used stock on resale sites like Craigslist. It's worth a look.

My approach here instead might be to pick up some aluminum coil stock, cut it to length, and bend it to fit around some hardboard siding (Masonite<sup>™</sup>). This is because your aluminum is *also* probably supported with fiberboard or foam. Hollow metal of that board height is likely to appear misshapen. I'd then install the hardboard, cut to match the existing siding, and wrap it with the aluminum. Paint as desired.